# How to find lipschitz constant of the gradiant of $\sqrt{1+x^2}$?

Tags: lipschitz-functions

I know $\left|\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right| \le 1$. But I don't know how to find $L$ that $\left|\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}-\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\right| \le L|x-y|$.

Would you please explain it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the function $f(x):=\sqrt{1+x^2}$ has second derivative $\dfrac{1}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}$, so $f$ is in $\mathrm C^2$.

> Clue: Lagrange's theorem will apply.

> Clue: Lagrange gives here that $|f'(x) -f'(y)| \leq |f''(z_0)||x-y|$ where $z_0$ is somewhere in $(x, y)$.

Comment: Isn't that just the mean value theorem?

Comment: @Troposphere Yes, Lagrange's theorem is also called Lagrange's MVT or simply MVT.

Comment: Does that differ from the usual mean value theorem? It looks like the ordinary one will do the job perfectly well here.

Comment: @Troposphere No, it's just a different name for the same thing you're referring to. There are other mean value theorems as well, of course (or different ways of stating). The version here is classically called Lagrange's mean value theorem. An example of another  form is Cauchy's mean value theorem.

Comment: Thanks but isn't the mean value theorem an equality?

Comment: @Mina Yes, it is an equality. Do you see how to get the inequality from the equality?